# JQuery Slider Implementation Issues

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to implement in slider in JQuery. I'm stuck up in one place. Here is my code so far.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Experimentation</title>
    <style type="text/css">

#container {
overflow:hidden;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 800px;
background-color: white;
}   


.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 10000;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow:hidden;
  }


.information1, .information2, .information3, .information4, .information5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.2;
  top: 150px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.information1 h3, .information2 h3,.information3 h3, .information4 h3, .information5 h3   {
 margin: 3px 3px; 
 text-align: center;
}

.leftbutton img {
cursor:pointer;
}

.rightbutton img {
cursor:pointer;
}

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var topInitial = "0";
      var topAfter = "150px";

      $(function() {

      $(".box1").mouseenter(function() {    
      $(".information1").animate({
      top: topInitial }, "normal"); });

      $(".box1").mouseleave(function() {
      $(".information1").animate({
      top: topAfter }, "normal"); });


      $(".box2").mouseenter(function() {    
      $(".information2").animate({
      top: topInitial }, "normal"); });

      $(".box2").mouseleave(function() {
      $(".information2").animate({
      top: topAfter }, "normal"); });

       $(".box3").mouseenter(function() {   
      $(".information3").animate({
      top: topInitial }, "normal"); });

      $(".box3").mouseleave(function() {
      $(".information3").animate({
      top: topAfter }, "normal"); });

       $(".box4").mouseenter(function() {   
      $(".information4").animate({
      top: topInitial }, "normal"); });

      $(".box4").mouseleave(function() {
      $(".information4").animate({
      top: topAfter }, "normal"); });

      $(".box5").mouseenter(function() {    
      $(".information5").animate({
      top: topInitial }, "normal"); });

      $(".box5").mouseleave(function() {
      $(".information5").animate({
      top: topAfter }, "normal"); });

      $(".leftbutton img").click(function() {
      $(".box1").animate({
      marginLeft: "-=200px" }, "fast"); });

      $(".rightbutton img").click(function() {
      $(".box1").animate({
      marginLeft: "+=200px" }, "fast"); });

     });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="leftbutton"><img src="left.gif"/></div>
  <div id="container">

  <span class="box1">
  <div class="information1">
  <h3> Criminal Penguins Having a Ball </h3>
  <p> You have never seen something like this before!</p>
  </div>
  </span>

  <span class="box2">
  <div class="information2">
  <h3> Criminal Penguins Having a Ball </h3>
  <p> You have never seen something like this before!</p>
  </div>  
  </span>

  <span class="box3">
  <div class="information3">
  <h3> Criminal Penguins Having a Ball </h3>
  <p> You have never seen something like this before!</p>
  </div>  
  </span>

  <span class="box4">
  <div class="information4">
  <h3> Criminal Penguins Having a Ball </h3>
  <p> You have never seen something like this before!</p>
  </div>  
  </span>


  <span class="box5">
  <div class="information5">
  <h3> Criminal Penguins Having a Ball </h3>
  <p> You have never seen something like this before!</p>
  </div>  
  </span>

  </div>
  <span class="rightbutton"><img src="right.gif"/></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Removing the comments from class="box5" gives me some issues which I've highlighted in the comments above. I would like to know where I'm going wrong. Also, for slider I'm planning to change the margin-left/right properties. Is that the right way a slider is implemented? Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me it's really difficult to tell what it is you want as a desired result.

I even threw [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/Vc4j8/) together to try and figure it out. Box 5 is not visible in the fiddle. But then, jsFiddle is set to juery 1.7. Why are you using jQuery 1.4???

Comment: Yes, box5 isn't visible to the user. If you do check up it's position in firebug, it comes at the bottom of box1. I want it to overflow to the right so that I can implement the slider functionality. Did you get my point? Also, the book I'm referring to right now uses jQuery 1.4.

Comment: Ok, I've made some changes to the code. Check it out now. The slider seems to give me the desired effect. I'll do some modifications and see if I encounter any other issues. Thanks. The design is not correct, however that is not my concern right now. I'm just focussing on the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this
http://www.slidedeck.com